# Microsoft Graph: Download file via Rest API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to download the contents of a sharepoint document via microsofts Graph API.

When I show the document's details on the sharepoint website, I see the following path in the document's details: 
`My Company Team Site > Documents > My Application > file.xlsx`

**Approach 1:**

Using the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), I can execute the following query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives`.
It returns a single object called "Documents" with this WebURL: `https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents`

However, I don't know how I proceed from there and get to the folder's sub-elements, all my attempts caused HTTP errors.

**Approach 2:**

Alternatively, I also tried to "get a sharepoint site based on it's relative path":
 `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myCompany.sharepoint.com:/`

This request also yields one result with the display name "My Company Team Site" and an ID looking like this: `myCompany.sharepoint.com,45aaf871-b578-0000-....`, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there and how the remaining URL should look like.

**Question:**

What's the correct approach? How can I iterate the "files within a folder" in sharepoint and how do I get the siteID/itemID of the documents/folders I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, lets try to connect the dots together.

> It is assumed file named `Guide.docx` is located under `Archive`
>   folder in library

**Approach 1**

> However, I don't know how I proceed from there and get to the folder's
>   sub-elements, all my attempts caused HTTP errors.

For this approach the following request demonstrates how to download a file:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root:/archive/guide.docx:/content
```

where `:/archive/guide.docx:/` is [path-based addressing syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online) used to target a file inside a folder

> **Note**: there is no need to explicitly specify path to library (`Shared Documents`) since it is a *default* drive

**Approach 2**

> This request also yields one result with the display name "My Company
>   Team Site" and an ID looking like this:
>   myCompany.sharepoint.com,45aaf871-b578-0000-...., but I'm not sure how
>   to proceed from there and how the remaining URL should look like.

Since `siteId` is determined (`myCompany.sharepoint.com,45aaf871-b578-0000..`) the following request demonstrates how to address a file by `site id` and `file path`:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites{site-id}/drive/root:/archive/guide.docx:/content
```

**References**

[Addressing resources in a drive on OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: This is working and I can get to the file I want to download, but as soon as I add `/content` I get an HTTP error again. I checked and I have all the needed [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for downloading. Do you have any idea why `/content` still causes an error?

Answer (score 2):

Get site id:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/yourtenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/lee
```

Get the files(item id) in your folder. (folder under my test library->MyDOc/Folder)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/drives/b!kan3K2m2N0Ww9Vn31kUuSLJVeywG43tAsaIcpv7Mme1FME9qbHnDRJrbrhnPTRCs/root:/folder:/children
```